# Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy but i don't have inline style in my app

Tags: html, css, security, content-security-policy

I want to add csp in my portfolio and i have removed all the inline style but still i'm getting the csp errors. I'am using scss which resolved in my main.css file and i'm importing this main.css file in my index.js file. I'm trying csp first time and i have read all most all question that are available on stack overflow but nothing works.

here is my meta tag for csp

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src 'self'; 
    img-src 'self' https://deploy-preview-12--sensational-bienenstitch-4b09b2.netlify.app; 
    frame-src https://app.netlify.com/;
    font-src fonts.gstatic.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com;
    style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com ;
    script-src 'self' https://netlify-cdp-loader.netlify.app ;
    connect-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com;">
```

I'm using netlify to deploy my app. I have also used google font and font awesome
The error msg says that something is wrong on line number 22
but this code is present on line number 22, i don't think this is the cause

```
background-color: var(--main-bg);
```

After expanding triangle i got this
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you click on the link in the output there, `main.css:22` what is there in the code? If you expand the error message, e.g. the triangle on the left, what additional information is there for you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are inserting a style element into your DOM, which is equivalent to an inline style element in the document. Some rewrite will be required to make this work without allowing 'unsafe-inline' for styles. The likely paths are one of these:

- Create a css file with the possible styles and toggle classnames if you need something to be dynamic.
- If there is a limited set of variations of the style element being added you can add the hash value of all of them to the CSP.
- Set a nonce attribute on the style element. This will require you to create a nonce for each page load that is set both in the CSP and on the style, with all the necessary wiring to set it in two different places.
- Compute the hash of the style and add it to the CSP. You will need to know the style element to be added at the time the page loads.

Comment: I didnt find out where i'm inserting the style element ?? my app is simple react app. just using scss only.

Comment: Click the code link in the error message?